# JSON via c# , extract array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have an long JSON that include array.

All the JSON is dynamic and i don't have const structure to this JSON.

Only i know is that "JSON" include this array.

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

I want with c#  extract an array of the first name  from this .

I tried to do that but not succeed.

Comment: *I tried to do that but not succeed*, how? Show us ...

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using JavaScriptSerializer?  Do you have an "employee" class declared in code?  You should be able to just use JavaScriptSerializer to parse it into an array of "employees," and then get their first names.  Any code you write will more than likely be recreating the wheel...  This is an example of deserializing into objects using the standard library (it's very simple):JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); var empArray= js.Deserialize<employee>(employees);... Then get first names as from any array.

Answer (score 0):

use json.net. Deserialize to dynamic.

```
dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserialzeObject(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

What I normally do is split the JSON string using the C# native String.Split

```
const string quote = "\""; //You can ignore this line if you like it just adds the "" as a constant string/char value!

string storedValue = "{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}" //The JSON value stored either from an HTTPWebRequest or some other method!

string[] str = storedValue.Split(new string[] {quote + "firstName" + quote + ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //Split the JSON firstName value!
```

So the compiler would essentially look for "firstName": and split the firstName value with all the other code, but then if you did str[1] it would also grab lastName value so what I always do after sending the HTTPWebRequest to receive the Request from the target server, and I split the ID I want I then split one final time at the "," to remove last name from the JSON code I want to spit!

```
string[] finalSplit = str.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

string output = finalSplit[0].ToString();
```

as far as I can tell the 'output' string value should equal the "John" value from your JSON code!

If you want to remove the quotes use the Regex.Replace() in C#.

```
using System.Net.RegularExpressions; //Import C# library using this code at the top of your class or above the Namespace declaration!

Regex.Replace(output, @quotes, ""); //The 'quotes' method was declared at the top of the first code block it was that code I said you could ignore if you really wanted to!
```

after removing the quotes the last thing to do is just place output into a label, textbox, or maybe even a file using System.IO.streamWriter!

Also btw how where you getting the JSON code from a file or VIA an HTTPWebRequest? If you are getting the JSON code from an HTTPWebRequest I recommend converting the code to UTF-8 just to be on the safe side!

Now I know there is a more official way to read JSON in C# but this is MY method and it works for me so I see no reason in using an official method if I have one that works just as well, but again this is just my opinion! :)

Comment: bad plan, just use netwonsoft json.net

Comment: Well I find this works for me and I thought I would share it to see if maybe the author would use it if they wanted something like this!

Comment: the problem is that this is a very fragile solution, it doesnt generalize